# returning a specific part of column name in a dataframe on a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following column names(for the reference I have mentioned only one row).
I would like to get the maximum size_cd amongst the   `encoded_feature.size_cd_0    encoded_feature.size_cd_1   encoded_feature.size_cd_2   encoded_feature.size_cd_3`. In this case it is `size_cd_0` has the maximum value i.e.24. I would like to return the number `0` from the column name as a return value.

Input dataframe:

| type_z | encoded_feature.size_cd_0 | encoded_feature.size_cd_1 | encoded_feature.size_cd_2 | encoded_feature.size_cd_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

required Output:
`0` i.e. the part following the `encoded_feature.size_cd_#`  (as this column has the max value)

I would appreciate your feedback on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html?highlight=filter#pandas.DataFrame.filter) to select columns and then [`pd.Series.argmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html)

```
df.filter(regex='encoded_feature.size_cd').apply(pd.Series.argmax, axis=1)
```

Other approach using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
(
    df
    .filter(regex='encoded_feature.size_cd')
    .idxmax(axis=1)
    .str
    .slice(-1)
)
```